# React Native ScrollView keep scroll position

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I scroll using the ScrollView component I always end up snapping to the top of the screen. However I would like if there is a way to make it keep my scroll position at the current position (presumably the last position I scrolled to).

For example, if it's at the bottom of the screen, instead of automatically going back to the top, I want it to stay there at the bottom of the screen.

I hope I haven't confused you.

Comment: Do you mean when the component is rendered?

Comment: @BenM Yes, I don't it to reset to 0 every time render() is called

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview component position is always fixed. Just inner content will move up and down unless you put your scrollview on an other scrollview or Flatlist. However,  that is not the correct way of using it.

Comment: But is there no way to prevent resetting to 0 every time it renders? Will it always snap to the top?